# Parallel.ForEach returns less results on Azure Webjobs

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, azure-webjobs, parallel.foreach

Running the following code on my local machine

```
Console.WriteLine("Loaded: " + records.Count);

        Parallel.ForEach(records, record =>
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var response = client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, Http + record.DomainName)).Result;
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode || !response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Host.EndsWith("domain.com"))
                    return;
                var finalDomain = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Host.Replace(Www, null);
                if (_resultsList.Add(finalDomain))
                    Console.WriteLine("Added: " + finalDomain);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        });

Console.WriteLine("Added: " + _resultsList.Count);
```

Writes the following to console

```
Loaded: 3556
Added: 1550
```

But when I upload it, and run it as an Azure Webjob I get a lot less domains returning.

```
Loaded: 3556
Added: 308
```

Replacing `Parallel.ForEach()` with a regular `foreach` returns the same number of domains on both, but it takes a lot longer. Why is `Parallel.ForEach()` not returning the same number of results on Azure Webjobs, as on my own machine?

Comment: Could it be because you are throwing away all errors?

Comment: I should have specified that this code is just checking which subdomains from a list are alive, or redirects to other subdomains on the same domain.

I'm throwing away all the errors, those links are dead

Comment: `"Why is Parallel.ForEach() not returning the same number of results on Azure Webjobs, as on my own machine?"` Look at the errors to find out!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons and as @usr aluded to, you would be catching either if you were not ignoring exceptions.  Here are 2 possible reasons, from least likely to most likely

1. Some SendAsync calls maybe failing from a Webjob due to environmental issues (misconfiguration, permissions, firewalls, etc)
2. _resultsList does not appear to be thread-safe.  Thus, multiple adds to it from different Parallel threads may result in an exception.  Use a lock() method to start a semaphore before adding to _resultsList collection

Comment: I'm catching `An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`. I assume this means that I'm trying to use too many sockets?

Comment: Now that you know the error, it's time to start googling :)  There are a number of possible issues, but we're missing the context of what you're trying to do and which sites are failing, etc